# What is the voltage on source of N-Channel FET

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

I am working on a circuit figure 1. I tried to monitor the voltage on the source of M5.

What I am expecting is when M5 is turn ON, it acts as a short, so it can be obtained by voltage divider law like figure 2 which is ~6.125V. What I am finding in the simulation is ~3V. Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Why do I have a voltage drop on R17.

Comment: II Kirchhoff's law does not allow this to happen. For the input loop, we have \$5V = V_{GS} + I_D*R_S\$ thus, the Source voltage is \$V_S = 5V - V_{GS}\$

Answer (score 2):

You aren't fully turning on the MOSFET since the source resistor is raising the source voltage.  It's in between full-off and full-on and is acting as a ~21.5k resistor.

Comment: I jumper a wire between Drain and Source. while cut-off 5V from the Gate. and still getting the same 2.95V.